# What is the English version of the Vietnamese idiom "như cá nằm trên thớt" - "like a fish on cutting board"

Tags: idioms, metaphors

We have a Vietnamese idiom, "như cá nằm trên thớt" - literally, "like a fish on cutting board". My apology for the rough translation because I regard myself as an English learner who is above the average a bit. The meaning of the idiom is: implying a dangerous and almost unescapable situation in which a person's life or fate is in someone's hands and seriously threatened.

I have looked for a similar expression in [the idioms section of thefreedictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com) and other websites such as [merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com) and [the OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/) but they appear to have other expressions that are not related to the word "fish".

Is there an English version or a metaphor of the mentioned idiom?

Besides, many presume the Vietnamese idiom to be exactly identical to the Japanese one. However, they do have a slightly different meaning regarding their contexts.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that, as fishing is substantially less of the english speaking world's economy (and fish make up less of its diet), it stands to reason that fish-related idioms may not directly translate. Still, there's some pretty close ones listed below.

Comment: Sticking with ***fish-based*** figurative usages relating to vulnerability in *a dangerous and almost inescapable situation*, you might like to note [***fish in a barrel***](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103345/) as previously addressed on ELU.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there metaphoric English expressions meaning “keeping composure at a fatal moment, never panicky”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162539/are-there-metaphoric-english-expressions-meaning-keeping-composure-at-a-fatal-m)

Comment: This is very similar (but not certain if it's identical) to a carp on a cutting board...

Comment: @medica: is a carp a fish?

Comment: @Mitch Is that a real question? Or am I missing a joke? My knowledge of biology is at the level where I can just about tell a birch tree from a walrus, and even I know that [a carp is a fish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carp).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It was a leading question. A carp is obviously a fish, so I don't understand how medica could possibly say 'not certain it's identical'.

Comment: @Mitch I think she meant she’s not certain whether this Vietnamese expression (‘like a fish on a cutting board’) is quite identical in meaning to the Japanese one linked to above (‘carp on a cutting board’), or whether the meanings are slightly different. The Japanese one contains an element of keeping calm in the face of danger, which (going by this question alone) the Vietnamese one does not seem to contain, so I would hazard that they are in fact **not** identical.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Wow. OK. I see now. Yes, despite having almost identical words, the description of each sound very different. I thought they couldn't possibly be different, but maybe they are. Abecedarian, are they the same proverb or not? Also, did any of the non-fish phrases match yours metaphorically?

Comment: it's unbelievable that everyone didn't just immediately point out that the answer is "a sitting duck"

Comment: @Mitch is the Pope Catholic?

Comment: @Mitch There are so many suggested idioms that are similar to one another to a certain extent. Also, I did look up the Japanese proverb and I have to say that its meaning is almost identical to ours. The only difference is perhaps, as you mentioned, the element of keeping calm in the face of danger. 
So far, there may have been two closest idioms in meaning: "like a lamb to the slaughter" and "a sitting duck".

Comment: Does the idiom imply anything else about the person who is in the situation? Are they aware of the situation? Do they have the power to change it? Are they calm, or panicked? Was it a situation they could have avoided? As the multiple answers and comments show, "in extreme danger" is pretty broad and there are a number of idioms that express that concept; any extra information at all that you can [edit] into the question would be a great help.

Comment: @Abecedarian as a heads up, I've asked whether the Vietnamese and Japanese phrases are related on the Japanese language stack exchange: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24360/is-%E4%BF%8E%E6%9D%BF%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%AE%E9%AF%89-related-to-the-vietnamese-phrase-nh%C6%B0-c%C3%A1-n%E1%BA%B1m-tr%C3%AAn-th%E1%BB%9Bt

Comment: ＠Medica, @Janus Bahs Jacquet. I assume that Vietnamese idiom, "như cá nằm trên thớt - like a fish on cutting board" and Japanese idiom, “まな板の上の鯉- A carp on the chopping board” resemble in the form, but different in the implication from the OP’s text. The point of the former is on a (hopeless) situation, while the spirit of the latter is on the attitude and the virtue of keeping composure even at the critical, hopeless situation.

Comment: Cont'd. Those who behave like a carp on the chopping board at battle field, business and political scene and whatsoever are respected as a man with unmatched composure as well guts in Japan. I don’t think "như cá nằm trên thớt” carries the similar psychological tone.

Comment: Being Vietnamese, I suggest the intent and usage in the context of following. The proverb conveys an inescapable situation for the fish regardless if the fish is innocent or not and usually from an external force. It commonly presents the greatest (physical) harm possible or metaphorically speaking under some extreme undesired situations that one can do what one want to the fish, just a matter of time and convenience. The fish may be somewhat aware of the situation but not able to do anything about it, or the fish is not even aware of the situation it is in.

Answer (score 25):

I would say ***like a lamb led to slaughter*** is the closest in meaning. The lamb is symbolic for its innocence. It will follow you happily, not knowing you are taking it to die. So this idiom implies a naivety on the part of the lamb, when in fact its life is in the hands of another. That seems to be the same as your meaning for the fish on the cutting board.

Another one we use is ***to be a sitting duck***. The duck is unaware of the danger it is in by remaining still. That makes it much easier to shoot.

The ***shooting fish in a barrel*** idiom is more implying that some task is very easy. It is not used from the fish's perspective.

Comment: As you point out, "sitting duck" is the obvious and exact equivalent in English.  (the other two you mention are irrelevant, or only vaguely close - but then dozens of phrases are vaguely close)

Comment: Better than "sitting" would be "dead": "After my accomplice told all, I was a dead duck."

Comment: I have only heard the first as **(like a) lamb to the slaughter**. That seems to be the most common phrasing, but others are widely used—some with *lambs* instead of *a lamb*, some with *led*, some without *the*.

Answer (score 19):

The closest expression I can think of is

> [have/put your head on the (chopping) block](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/have-put-your-head-on-the-block)

That is 'to risk a bad thing happening to you by doing something or helping someone.'

Other animal-based analogies which could be used in a similar context to the one you mention, but have a slightly different use are ['like pigs to the slaughter'](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/like+pigs+to+the+slaughter) and ['like fish in a barrel.'](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/like+shooting+fish+in+a+barrel)

edit: As Joe has pointed out in comments, ['like a sitting duck'](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/like+a+sitting+duck) is also a good match. The key difference between the chopping block and the duck comparison is whether the agent (person/company/team etc) in question is aware of their own vulnerability and/or has put themselves there deliberately.

Comment: We do have ['like a fish out of water'](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+fish+out+of+water), but it lacks the same sense of immenent danger, and is now fairly similar to ['an odd fish'](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/odd+fish) : someone who stands out from a group as not belonging in a certain situation.

Comment: ['Like fish in a barrel'](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/like+shooting+fish+in+a+barrel) is probably the closest, but it's inverted compared to the vietnamese situation described. Instead of describing the situation from the fish's hopeless perspective, it is usually used to describe a situation from the perspective of the person outside the barrel, doing the shooting.

Comment: Hi Sam - "like a sitting duck" is the obvious answer.  putting your head on the chopping block is a little similar (it's when you "stick your neck out" actively to help someone), but, "like a sitting duck" is simply exactly the same as the vietnamese saying in question.

Comment: @JoeBlow I've added your suggestion to my answer - for some reason I understood the question to mean someone knowingly at risk, which coloured my original answer (where obliviousness is a key component of the sitting duck).

Comment: The metaphorical block is also commonly used for things as well as people. Anything that can be discontinued, halted or expunged can be said to be 'on the chopping block'. Example: "The company had a down quarter, so now my project, maybe even our whole department, is on the chopping block." This borrows more from the visual of chopping wood with an axe (which is quite similar to execution by beheading). +1

Answer (score 6):

You could be *[up a creek:](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/up+a+creek)*

> Also, **up shit creek**; **up the creek (without a paddle)**: In trouble, in a serious predicament, as in" If the check doesn't arrive today I'm up a creek", or "The car wouldn't start, so I was up the creek without a paddle." This slangy idiom conjures up the image of a stranded canoeist with no way of moving (paddling) the canoe.  *[idioms.freedictionary.com]*

Answer (score 4):

There is

- "behind the eight-ball" (at a disadvantage)
- "under the gun" (literally in mortal peril but usually used in situations of stress rather than danger)
- "on one's last legs" (dilapidated or exhausted to the point of collapse)
- "in the jaws of death" (usually meaning physical danger)
- "circling the bowl" (approaching defeat or failure)
- "one foot in the grave" (physically ill)
- "hanging by a thread" (facing imminent disaster, often in a professional or financial sense)
- "the vultures are circling" (typically said of business problems)

Answer (score 4):

I think the best analogy would be phrase "to be a sitting duck". Googling the original phrase "như cá nằm trên thớt" as first result shows article about situation in Ukraine. After translating it with Google  you can see that [article](http://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=en&sl=vi&u=http://baodatviet.vn/quoc-phong/binh-luan-quan-su/kiev-xin-cho-quan-thoat-vay-mariupol-nhu-ca-nam-tren-thot-3055689/&prev=search) uses original phrase to express extreme vulnerability and helplessness. This indicates "to be a sitting duck" is better match than "like lambs to the slaughter" as that one is more about naivity than peril.

Answer (score 2):

Two similes come to mind:

- **"like lambs to the slaughter"**  This could fit if the fish lies quietly on the board, unaware of danger.

  > - Innocently and helplessly, without realizing the danger. For example, She agreed to appeal to the board, little knowing she would go like a lamb to the slaughter . [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/like+a+lamb+to+the+slaughter)
- **"like a frightened rabbit"** although it lacks the sense of danger or imminent death.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with *between a rock and a hard place*, which I am guessing originally referred to someone having their head smashed in on a sacrificial altar. In Vietnam, fish are usually still alive when they are cut up!

Comment: `originally referred to someone having their head smashed in on a sacrificial altar` [citation needed]

Comment: @mikeTheLiar I remember reading the proposal in William Safire's book, *On Language*, p. 29.

Comment: between a rock and a hard place means - unsurprisingly - tht you are stuck between two difficult choices. it has nothing to do with being a sitting duck, or a fish on the board.

Comment: In every telling I've run across, *between a rock an a hard place* is freely interchangeable with *between Scylla* (a rock) *and Charybdis* (which, to a mariner, would be a hard place).

Comment: "between a rock and a hard plaice" would be in keeping with the "fish" theme, I guess ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Another that I don't see mentioned yet: "Out of the frying pan, into the fire" -- though that's more escaping a bad situation into an even worse one.

Answer (score 1):

To be expressive as possible in English, do not use clichés. "Like a fish on a cutting board" is comprehensible in English without borrowing some antique colloquialism.

Answer (score 1):

I live in Vietnam, so I understand this sentence means, but my English is not well so cannot describe to help you understand more.
But I will say briefly.
Ex: She/He get a trouble but they are as totall lost, they don't know what to do, they don't know who to ask, To solve the problem. That is some means of that sentence.
**Cá nằm trên thớt**

Comment: Sounds a bit like the English expression [*a fish out of water*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fish+out+of+water) (dictionary.reference.com).

Answer (score 0):

"In the mouth of the lion's den" or "Walking into the lion's den".

"I am sunk."

Answer (score 0):

"Like a cornered rat" is an idiom that suggests that the "rat" in question is in imminent mortal danger. However, this phrase usually also carries the connotation that the person being cornered is unpleasant/nasty/dishonest (the "villain") and that the person(s) doing the cornering are virtuous/on the side of right (the "hero(es)").

(As Malvolio notes in the comment below, you should note that the most common use of this phrase is to warn the attacker of the potential for the desperate foe to retaliate violently, even against the odds.)

Comment: The proverbial cornered rat will resort to extreme tactics, such as attacking a much larger animal.  The phrase is meant to warn _the attacker_ about his desperate adversary.

Comment: @Malvolio That's a good point, and I concede it. Like others, I wanted to give the questioner another alternative (which might, as in this case, have a slightly different shade of meaning). I've edited my answer to clarify.

Comment: Rethinking this, I realized that "like a cornered rat", means "liable to resort to extreme measures", but "cornered like a rat" means "in danger and lacking options" (which, of course, will often lead to extreme measures).  Both phrases come from the unsavory sport of [rat-baiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rat-baiting).

Answer (score 0):

Variants of ***like ants under a magnifying glass*** may carry the meaning.

Answer (score -1):

I think it depends on how the phrase is being used, and like some idioms, it could have different meaning in context.  Like a fish on cutting board could mean something is about to end, it could mean time is of the essence, it could mean a decision needs to be made, it could mean it's too late to make any decision.  The important question in my mind is, 'how is it used'?
Some idioms that come to mind include:
"**shit or get off the pot**"
"the sword of Damocles is upon us.."