# What is an idiom, phrase or expression for situation such as "throw a pigeon among cats"

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, idioms

Normally there is a idiom "throw a cat among pigeons" but what is being  inquired here is  "throwing a pigeon among cats" where cats are predator and pigeon is the prey and pigeon is trapped between the predator cats who are out to get at the drop of a hat.

Typically, an example of this would be a employee (the pigeon) working for more than 1 tyrant boss (predator) ideally for more than 4-5 toxic tyrant bosses  (predators) helicoptering you, ripping you off of your negligible mistake, etc..

PS: Basically the boss here can be empty suit freeloaders

Comment: sitting duck - a person or thing with no protection against an attack or other source of danger.

Comment: Please see this helpful distinction between "Fish in a barrel" and "sitting ducks." https://english.stackexchange.com/a/103347/3306

Comment: The duck is unaware until someone fires the first shot. Then, not so much.

Comment: To be in the crosshairs - "be the object of intense observation or scrutiny, usually as a result of some wrongdoing or unpopular opinion, etc., or to be in a position to be attacked or criticized." - "singled out for blame, harassment, or other unwanted attention"

Comment: Do you mean "throw the cat among the pigeons"? Which means "to focus on, disrupt, or antagonize" a group by adding an invariant factor to it? Such as introducing a disruptive personality to a group of common thinking people?

Comment: The answer is simply "throw to the lions" or "... wolves"

Comment: An interesting modern one is "Shark Tank" from the TV show of the same name.

Comment: I really wish there were fewer idioms using violence toward animals. Who skins cats anyway? Sheesh.

Comment: The expression is *put* the cat among the pigeons and it does *not* mean what you think it does. It just means to stir up trouble. A suggestion: don’t bring your personal situation with your boss into questions here. Phrase them in a general way. And do some research before posting.

Comment: Which dialect/language uses that idiom? I've never heard it before.

Answer (score 69):

If someone is sacrificing the employee in order to satisfy the other tyrant bosses, then perhaps

**Throw someone to the wolves**

> Fig. to sacrifice someone to save the rest; to abandon someone to harm. (Fig. on the image of giving one person to the wolves to eat so the rest can get away.)

[The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/throw+him+to+the+wolves)

Answer (score 42):

Probably:

***[Throw to the lions:](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/thrown-to-the-lions)***

> Figuratively, to be thrown to the lions is to be placed in a difficult situation for which one is completely unprepared: *“To put that new teacher in front of those unruly students is to throw her to the lions.”*

Origin:

> During Roman persecutions Christians were thrown  to the lions in the Colosseum.

(Dictionary.com)

Comment: This has connotations of providing entertainment (circus) so not ideal for OPs situation.

Comment: @KalleMP - not really, the origin is different and much less entertaining. See the link in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I am misunderstanding something.  Throwing the disbelievers to be eaten by lions on a circus day was intended to be entertainment.  Your link does not offer any other origin or I did not find it.

Comment: @KalleMP The saying is much older than the Romans. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_in_the_lions%27_den (or read the original Bible story, the Book of Daniel chapter 6).

Comment: @alephzero +1 That certainly pre-dates Christian persecution by the Romans.  However used as a expression __Thrown into the lions den__ might describe trial then deliverance by personal fortitude while __Thrown to the lions__ might mean ruin while an object of entertainment.  I think they could be classified with two different meanings, maybe, perhaps.  Though the Daniel event was likely also intended to be entertaining to his detractors.

Comment: @alephzero - though it was considered a form of “entertainment” the meaning has changed with time. Nowadays is you through someone to the lions it is not for fun.

Comment: Dictionary.com needs a proofreader.  Not all Christians call themselves Catholic, and none did in the time referred to.  :-)

Comment: there is absolutely no connotation of "circus" in today's usage, @KalleMP .  It has nothing to do with it.  At all. You are utterly incorrect.  If a young employe has to present to the board he is being "thrown to the lions".  Simple.

Comment: @Fattie I think you might be overstating your position there a bit. I haven’t heard this expression before (only the lions’ den one) and would assume that the divergence from what I consider the “standard” expression (wolves) would be an intentional allusion to throwing christians to lions I.e. for entertainment. That doesn’t mean it’s common, or the “right” origin, but there’s certainly a risk it will be interpreted that way.

Comment: @Jeff, I mean a fundamental issue on this site is, say we ask the simple question "How do you spell table?"  The only meaningful answer is *as a broadly experienced native English speaker, i believe that the most common usage is _ answer here _".  There is no "definitive" answer conceptually possible.  Language is just a social norm.  (Looking in a dictionary for the answer "how is table spelled" is meaningless; a dictionary is literally a few people saying *as a broadly experienced native English speaker, I believe that the most common usage is _ answer here _".)  Sooooo....

Comment: .. on this issue, as on every other detail on this site, I can only say "Hmm, I don't really see that Jeff, I find 'throw to the lions' to be the common expression in our era, and the otehr two variants (wolves/den) just sound like misspeakings to me..."  (Note too that origins mean nothing, what matters is current use.  (For example, I've given up trying to tell people they are using "decimate" and "apocryphal" utterly, utterly incorrectly based on what the words, well, actually mean!)  Anyways!  Fair enough.

Comment: I don't see much emphasis around motive in the question, but certainly 'Thrown to the lions' suggests the thrower would witness the outcome, while 'Thrown to the wolves' suggests more that the victim has been left to their fate. I don't think this answer is wrong as the question appears to only relate to the victim being put into a dangerous situation.

Answer (score 15):

The more modern version of this sentiment is

***to throw someone under the bus***.

As The Free Dictionary notes, it means

> 1. To exploit someone's trust for one's own purpose, gain, or agenda; to harm someone through deceit or treachery.
>      *Senator Davis was supposed to be working with me to bridge the gap between Democrats and Republicans on the issue of gun control, but, instead, she threw me under the bus to get a boost in the polls with her constituency.*
>      *The investment company threw its clients under the bus when it chose to redirect their hard earned money into various Ponzi schemes that benefited only a few board members at the top.*
> 2. To avoid blame, trouble, or criticism by allowing someone else to take responsibility.
>      *Tommy was caught with the marijuana in his backpack, but he threw me under the bus and said it belonged to me.*
>      *Our manager never hesitates to throw an underling under the bus when something goes wrong in the office.*

That last example seems like it would go very well with your description.

Comment: I *think* the idiom OP is after is to do with multiple problems, not a single one. And yes, I do know buses sometimes come in threes.

Comment: In my experience, as well as in the definitions quoted above, "to throw someone under the bus" does not include any significant connotation of putting someone in the (figurative) situation of prey among predators, which was the OP's question.

Comment: @LarsH: agreed.  In the OP's hypothetical case, one of those bosses likely will throw you under the bus after a minor mistake (or even if you're innocent), if there is any blame they can shift your way.  But that's a specific-incident thing, not the general situation.

Comment: That is an American idiom, not really used in British English. Not saying it's wrong: just something to be aware of if the OP has a particular audience.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to escape the same idiomatic throwing a prey to a predator:

> Walking (or Forced to walk) through a minefield.

Where any misstep would obviously result in your death (scolding, criticism, demotion, etc).

> Sally's new project was like walking through a minefield. Everywhere she turned, someone was waiting to revel in her mistakes.

This might not be the exact situation you're referring to, but frequently in these situations:

> You're damned if you do and damned if you don't.

Meaning that you're in a dilemma that cannot be solved easily. Whatever you do will displease one person while pleasing the other.

Comment: Walk a minefield, good one. There's also "run the gauntlet:"

Answer (score 2):

As a (wryly or darkly) humorous description of the situation, **a pigeon among the cats** would work just fine, and would be understood as an inversion of the common phrase:

> Man, working for those guys was the worst job I ever had. You could
>   say they really set a pigeon among the cats when they placed me there!

A web search shows that *A Pigeon among the Cats* has been used as the title of [a crime novel](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4041937-a-pigeon-among-the-cats#) and [a volume of poetry](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/42551417-a-pigeon-among-the-cats?ac=1&from_search=true).

Answer (score 0):

There is also **Throwing firecrackers**

This can be combined with various settings

**Throwing firecrackers in church**
**Throwing firecrackers off an overpass**
**Throwing firecrackers in the toilet**

etc.

Comment: I'm not sure how _throwing firecrackers_ corresponds to the concept of _throwing a pigeon among cats_.

Comment: 'Throwing firecrackers in the toilet'? That's a damp squib, surely. Not an answer to the question.

Comment: I haven't heard this as an expression really. It's more an actual event.

Answer (score 0):

**The sharks are circling**

> If the sharks are circling, then something is in danger and its enemies are getting ready for the kill.
>
> [UsingEnglish.com](https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/sharks+are+circling.html)

This fits very well for the situation of having multiple bosses waiting to tear you apart the moment they see an opportunity to strike.

(Unlike *vultures* circling, which means waiting for something to die / fail *on its own* so carrion eaters can feast on the corpse.  e.g. creditors waiting to repossess property from a company struggling to keep up with payments, and people waiting to rehire any valuable employees.  Vultures circling as an idiom has no implication of predators surrounding the thing that's in trouble.)

---

**This doesn't fit the sense of *being placed into* this situation, though.**  Throwing someone to the wolves is a better fit for that, as @rajah9's answer points out.

But once in this situation, you might say "The situation at work feels like sharks are circling".  (Although that sounds kind of clumsy and isn't the best example of usage.  edits welcome with a better example.)